# Gradle - how to exclude Findbugs on /src/test/java

Tags: gradle, findbugs

Is there a way to exclude Findbugs execution on classes under /src/test/java. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
classes = classes.filter {
   !it.path.contains("**classes\\test\\org*")
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure. [The documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html) of the Findbugs extension says:

> sourceSets : The source sets to be analyzed as part of the check and build tasks.

And the example just above shows an example doing exactly what you want:

```
apply plugin: "findbugs"

findbugs {
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
}
```

i.e. only analyze the main sourceSet, and not the test sourceSet.

Comment: I tried that but it still executes the findbugsTest. I see the following in the logs.                                                        Deprecated dynamic property: "sourceSets" on "task ':findbugsIntegTest'", value: "[source set 'main']".
Deprecated dynamic property "sourceSets" created in multiple locations.

Comment: It is working in findbugs{}, now with tasks.withType(FindBugs) {}

Answer (score 3):

For Gradle 4.5.1

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

findbugs {
    findbugsTest.enabled = false
}
```

It isn't mentioned anywhere in documentation, at least I, as 1 day gradle user, don't find it, but it works.