# Jenkins module dependencies

Tags: android, git, opencv, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to perfom static analysis on my android project host in a private Git. I am using opencvLibrary as a separate module but this module is not in my git (as it takes lot of memory).

My problem is that Jenkins wants to load opencv dependency but it's not on a git, how can I tell jenkins not to load opencv ?

See my error below :

> Could not resolve project :openCVLibrary340.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>            project :app > project :tech
>
> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :openCVLibrary340: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: just exclude openCV in the pom.xml when checking SCA

Comment: This is for maven but i'm using gradle and I find nothing about sca exclusion, do you have any idea ? 
I found something to exclude from compilation (but not only sca) if it can help (in build.gradle file) : 
`configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'openCVLibrary340'
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920867/gradle-how-to-exclude-findbugs-on-src-test-java